# AltBeacon not detect Micropchip rn4870 beacon, detect only iBeacons

Tags: java, android, altbeacon

I use Android Beacon Library AltBeacon. **Not detect Microchip rn4870**, shows only iBeacons. I use these BeaconParsers to detect all beacons around. Can someone explain how can i detect **Microchip rn4870**.

```
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    // To detect proprietary beacons, you must add a line like below corresponding to your beacon
    // type.  Do a web search for "setBeaconLayout" to get the proper expression.

    ArrayList<BeaconParser> parsers = new ArrayList<>();

    parsers.add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
    parsers.add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("x,s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=20,d:3-3,d:4-5,d:6-7,d:8-11,d:12-15"));
    parsers.add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19"));
    parsers.add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=10,p:3-3:-41,i:4-20v"));
    parsers.add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    parsers.add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
    parsers.add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_TLM_LAYOUT));
    parsers.add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_URL_LAYOUT));
    parsers.add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.URI_BEACON_LAYOUT));
    parsers.add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.ALTBEACON_LAYOUT));

    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().addAll(parsers);
    beaconManager.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Understand that Microchip rn4870 is a Bluetooth LE module and not necessarily a beacon transmitter.  You can build a beacon transmitter with this hardware, but that requires loading firmware onto it that transmits a particular beacon format.  Once you do so, it might transit iBeacon, AltBeacon or various Eddystone packets.

Bottom line: The problem is not with the code shown in the question, the problem is on the transmitter side.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, a tutorial on how to load custom beacon firmware onto a rn4870 is a bit beyond the scope of a question for StackOverflow.com.  You might check with the vendor to see if they provide any such reference firmware.